# ask make like '_php%' convert to active record

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, model

I have a query in model using active record , my query is like this

```
SELECT MID(id,1,1) id_depan_user,MID(id,5,10) id_belakang_user ,
id, nama_lengkap from user where id like '_001%'
```

how to convert the part in where like condition `id like '_001%'` I want to make that to be active record, my problem just at like condition like that.

this is my full code

```
    function get_id_child($id_parent){
    $this->db->select('MID(id,1,1) id_depan_user',false);
    $this->db->select('MID(id,5,LENGTH(id)) id_belakang_user',false);
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->like('id', '_'.$id_parent,'after');
    $query =$this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: what is your CI version? and what did you tried?

Comment: try this `$this->db->like('id','_001','after')`

Comment: Where you convert other part of your query into Active record??

Comment: i use version 2.2 my problem just at like statement, but if i try like this i get error `$this->db->like('id ', '_'.$id, 'after');`

Comment: comment/edit question with your full code that you tried to convert the query.

Comment: i have update my question with my full query

Comment: I don't see any problem to your query.What error message you getting?remember CI will replace `_` with `\_`

Comment: But the result it's different with that. .

Comment: If i try my query in mysql server  using _ and '\_' it's shown different ressult @shaiful islam

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->like('id ', '_001', 'after');
```

Comment: so if the id is from variable i just use like this? `$this->db->like('id ', '_'.$id, 'after');` is that right?

Comment: @nanasjr yes.But careful about your CI version. look documentation of [CI-3](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data)

Comment: totally agree with @ShaifulIslam which version of CI you use??

Comment: i use Codeigniter version 2.2

Comment: @NithinKrishnanP your answer contains only code.Code only answer is not good answer.Try to explain the answer otherwise your answer is same as my comment.

Comment: @NithinKrishnanP what do you mean by time of posting?I just advised you to how to write a good answer.take it positively.Even your answer comes 1min latter after my comment.Code only answers goes to low quality posts review and people vote to delete it.Hope your answer will not be voted for delete.

Answer (score 1):

Use this . you need to concate your variable with _ and assign  it to variable your also remove quotes from like query

```
function get_id_child($id_parent) {
    $id = "_" . $id_parent;// assign it to variable
    $this->db->select('MID(id,1,1) AS id_depan_user', FALSE);
    $this->db->select('MID(id,5,10) AS id_belakang_user', FALSE);
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->select('nama_lengkap');
    $this->db->like('id', $id, 'after');// use after in your query
    $query = $this->db->get("user");
    $result = $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: @nanasjr that's why we ask you to post your full code

Comment: But wait. I have a new problem again. Now the problem is the query shown  'like '\_001%' but that different with want i want. What i want is 'like _001%'

Comment: can you check your query parameter and paste your query to identify your problem

Comment: i change my condition with another algorithm hehe